# Not able to replicate AJAX using Python Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, ajax, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to replicate ajax request from a web page (https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/Data/DataTables.aspx). AJAX is initiated when we select values from dropdowns.

I am using the following request using python, but not able to see the response as in Network tab of the browser.

```
import bs4
import requests
import lxml

ses = requests.Session()
ses.get('https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/Data/DataTables.aspx')
headers_dict = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
    }
url = 'https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/Ajax2018.aspx/ReturnTabularDMAreaPercent_urban'
req_data = {'area':'00064', 'statstype':'1'}
resp = ses.post(url,data = req_data,headers = headers_dict)
    
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.content,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: what is your variable `state`? I cant run your code, because `state` is not defined.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak updated

Answer (score 2):

You need to add several things to your request to get an Answer from the server.

1. You need to convert your `dict` to `json` to pass it as string and not as `dict`.
2. You also need to specify the type of `request-data` by setting the request header to `Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8`

with those changes I was able to request the correkt data.

```
import bs4
import requests

ses = requests.Session()
ses.get('https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/Data/DataTables.aspx')
headers_dict = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
url = 'https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/Ajax2018.aspx/ReturnTabularDMAreaPercent_urban'
req_data = json.dumps({'area':'00037', 'statstype':'1'})
resp = ses.post(url,data = req_data,headers = headers_dict)
    
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.content,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Quite a tricky problem I must say.

Comment: There is no need to try to turn a python dict into json via quotation marks. Requests will take care of that for you and if it didn't you should use json.dumps(pythondict).

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot that `req_data` is not constant. I added `json.dumps` but left the rest unchanged to not infringe on your answer. @EricTruett

Answer (score 2):

From the requests documentation:

> Instead of encoding the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly
> using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be
> encoded automatically:

```py
>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
>>> r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Then, to get the output, call `r.json()` and you will get the data you are looking for.